# Reset System.Timers.Timer to prevent Elapsed event

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, timer

I am trying to use the `Timer` to trigger an event to send data across the network.  I created a simple class to debug.  Basically I have a `List<string>` I'd like to send.  I want the following to happen:

1. Add string to `List`
2. Start `Timer` for 10 seconds
3. Add second string to `List` before `Timer.Elapsed`
4. Restart `Timer` back at 10 seconds.

So far I have this:

```
public static List<string> list;
public static Timer timer;
public static bool isWiredUp = false;

public static void Log(string value) {
    if (list == null) list = new List<string>();
    list.Add(value);

    //this does not reset the timer, elapsed still happens 10s after #1
    if (timer != null) {
        timer = null;
    }

    timer = new Timer(10000);
    timer.Start();
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.AutoReset = false;

    if (!isWiredUp) {
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(SendToServer);
        isWiredUp = true;
    }
}

static void SendToServer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    timer.Enabled = false;
    timer.Stop();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `Stop` function followed immediately by the `Start` function to "restart" the timer.  Using that you can create the `Timer` when the class is first created, wire up the Elapsed event at that time, and then do nothing but call those two methods when an item is added.  It will either start, or restart, the timer.  Note that calling `Stop` on a timer that hasn't yet been started just does nothing, it doesn't throw an exception or cause any other problems.

```
public class Foo
{
    public static List<string> list;
    public static Timer timer;
    static Foo()
    {
        list = new List<string>();
        timer = new Timer(10000);
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Elapsed += SendToServer;
    }

    public static void Log(string value)
    {
        list.Add(value);
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Start();
    }

    static void SendToServer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO send data to server

        //AutoReset is false, so neither of these are needed
        //timer.Enabled = false;
        //timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Note that rather than using a `List` it's very possible that you want to use a `BlockingCollection<string>` instead.  This has several advantages.  First, the `Log` methods will work if called at the same time from multiple threads; as is multiple concurrent logs could break the list.  It also means that `SendToServer` can be taking items out of the queue at the same time that new items are added.  If you use a `List` you'll need to `lock` all access to the list (which might not be a problem, but isn't as straightforward).

Comment: From the question I understand that he wants to accumulate data in the list and send them once only after 10 seconds since last addition to list has elapsed. He wants to avoid SendToServer being called twice if he adds data to the list two times three seconds apart. I could be wrong, but that's how I read it.

Comment: @zespri That's exactly how I read it to.  That is exactly what this code does.

Comment: even using a timer.. this is a bad idea.. There is no locking, no form of synchronization.. A timer is the absolute worst way to go about doing this, he should reconsider how he is solving this problem.

Comment: The only problem is when the `Start()` function is called a second time, it doesn't delay the `Elapsed` event.

Comment: @MatthewSanford The synchronization needs to be done *in addition* to use a Timer, and is an entirely separate issue from the question at hand.  Yes, he needs to address that issue, but that's not what the question is asking about.

Comment: From debugging the time of adding each item, I've found that the `Elapsed` event fires exactly 10s after the first `.Start()`, regardless of `.Start()` being called again.

Comment: @tedski Sorry, that functionality applies to other types of `Timer` classes.  For this class you just need to call `Stop` and then start, which is still a simple enough change.  See edit.

Comment: Awesome, that answered my question. I am going to have to look into what @MatthewSanford was talking about now.

Comment: @tedski See the last paragraph of my post which addresses those issues.  Just use a `BlockingCollection` instead of a list and you should be fine.

Comment: Note that `.Stop()` will fire an `Elapsed` event.
the best way is to remove the event handler and add it again :
`timer.Elapsed -= myEventHandler;
 timer.Stop();
 timer.Elapsed += myEventHandler;
 timer.Start();`

Comment: @rednaks No, calling `Stop` doesn't fire the elapsed event.  If you call `Stop` right around the same time as the event is about to fire, it's possible for there to be a race condition in which the event is fired after calling `Stop` because it wasn't called quickly enough to be able to stop the handler.  There's a big difference there.  A `Timer`, for all sorts of reasons, is only going to be an approximation; it's precision is limited, and that is a problem that is inherent to the `Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is very easy to achieve with IObservable (Rx).

Let us simplify matters by declaring a `Subject<string>` as your list to push onto using .OnNext. Once you have your subject, an observable, you can do what you want with a single 'line' of System.Reactive.Linq. This is illustrated in the following pseudo-c#

```
 subject
.Buffer(<your timespan>,1)   //buffer until either a value is added or the timeout expires
.Subscribe(x => 
   { 
      if (x.Count == 0)  //the timeout expired so send on
      {
         SendAccumulatedListToServer(<your list>);   
         <clear your list>
      }   
      else
      {
         <your list>.Add(x);
      }
   });
```

Answer (score -5):

What you are implementing is totally the wrong way to go about doing this.  Have a look at the consumer producer model:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601.aspx

What you are trying to do is very commonly called the Consumer/Producer dataflow model. Essentially you have something generating a list of data that is to be sent somewhere, rather than sending it each time an item is added to the list you would like to send them in groups.. So you have a producer (the code putting data to be sent) and a consumer (the code sending the data).

Generally this problem is solved by spawning a thread that watches the list (usually a queue) and sends the data at regulary intervals, the best way to do this is using an EventWaitHandle.

Here is some very simplified code as an example

```
    class ServerStuff
{
    public void Init()
    {
        datatosend = new List<string>();
                    exitrequest = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset); //This wait handle will signal the consumer thread to exit
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_RunThread));
        t.Start(); // Start the consumer thread...
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        exitrequest.Set();
    }

    List<string> datatosend;
    EventWaitHandle exitrequest;

    public void AddItem(string item)
    {
        lock (((ICollection)datatosend).SyncRoot)
            datatosend.Add(item);
    }

    private void RunThread()
    {
        while (exitrequest.WaitOne(10 * 1000)) //wait 10 seconds between sending data, or wake up immediatly to exit request
        {
            string[] tosend;
            lock (((ICollection)datatosend).SyncRoot)
            {
                tosend = datatosend.ToArray();
                datatosend.Clear();
            }

            //Send the data to Sever here...

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your link shows "This topic is obsolete." and does not contain useful information.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about or what that page is supposed to be telling me

Comment: Thanks, this looks more digestible. I accepted the other answer for now, I have a meeting but will look over your response after.

Comment: This code doesn't do what is requested in the OP, and honestly isn't a particularly good implementation of the producer/consumer model.  Your code is set to send data every 10 seconds, regardless of when data is added.  He wants to send data 10 seconds after the last time data was added to the list (resetting any time new data is added).  Your code doesn't do that.  Next, your consumer is creating a new thread just to sit around doing nothing almost all of the time; that's wasting a lot of resources.  Financially, the synchronization mechanisms used here are quite out of date.

Comment: 1. What exactly do you think a timer does?
2. Adding to send 10 seconds after the data is requested is as simple as adding another EventWaitHAndle
3. This is the method recommended everywhere...
4.  Lastly this is the best use of the resources... perhaps you should read the link I provided.

Using a timer to do this is at best a very novice mistake.. but to each their own.

Comment: 1. If you don't reset it, and have `AutoReset=true`, the same thing.  When it's not set to auto reset and is reset when an item is added, something quite different. 2. Then add it so that your code does what the question asks. 3. No, it's not.  If you want proof, read your own link, it recommends a very different approach. 4. No, it's *not* the best use of resources, it burns a dedicated thread needlessly.  Perhaps *you* should read your own link.  It seems you're thinking about the first link you posted now marked "obsolete".  That should give you a hint. How is using a timer a mistake?

Comment: I find it kinda funny that you downvote my answer, despite the fact that it works, because I downvoted your answer because it *doesn't* work.